# AWK to skip lines until matching a character and afterwards perform calculation

Tags: bash, awk

I have a 2 files with the following structure:

file1:

```
# Some comments on the file
# I am a line
# I am a new line
# I am yet a new line
 
# A value in the next line
123
Values
(
1
2
3
4
5
)
```

file2:

```
# Some comments on the file
# I am a line
# I am a new line

# A value in the next line
123 
Values
(
1.1
2.1
3.1
4.1
5.1
)
```

The expected outcome would be a file with the absolute differences

```
0.1
0.1
0.1
0.1
0.1
```

I would like to know the absolute difference between the values in parenthesis between both files.

Currently I have a function of:

```
foo()
{
    paste $1 $2 | awk -F'\t' 'function abs(x){return ((x < 0.0) ? -x : x)} {print abs($1 - $2)}' > outputFile
}
```

This works but checks all the file. If my headers don't match I will get problems..
Is there anyway to tell awk to just apply the functions after finding the opening parenthesis?

Best Regards

Answer (score 4):

You already know how to make and use an `abs()` function so just add it to this:

```
$ awk '
    /\(/{f=1; next} /)/{f=0} !f{next}
    NR==FNR { file1[++a]=$0; next }
    { print $0 - file1[++b] }
' file1 file2
0.1
0.1
0.1
0.1
0.1
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
foo() {
    paste $1 $2 | awk -F'\t' '
        function abs(x){return ((x < 0.0) ? -x : x)}
        /\(/{f=1}
        /\)/{f=0}
        (f) {print abs($1 - $2)}
    ' > outputFile
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. This does not seem to work for cases with uneven headers

Comment: [Never name a variable `l`](https://www.google.com/search?q=never+name+a+variable+l)

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** if comments contain parentheses, additional processing are needed. They can be removed beforehand or skipped.

**Variant № 1**

```
awk -F'\n' '
function abs(n) {
    return (n < 0) ? -n : n
}

NR == 2 {
    for(i = 2; i < NF; i++) {
        arr[i] = $i
    }
}

NR == 5 {
    for(i = 2; i < NF; i++) {
        print abs(arr[i] - $i)
    }
}
' RS='[)(]' file_1.txt file_2.txt
```

**Explanation**

`RS='[)(]'` separates records by parentheses instead of newline. Thus, for such example:

```
some text\nValues(\nnum1\nnum2\nnum3\n...)\n
```

the result will be (parentheses disappears):

```
record1              record2                    record3
some text\nValues    \nnum1\nnum2\nnum3\n...    \n
```

`-F'\n'` separates fields by newline. Splited **record2** looks this way:

```
'empty' num1    num2    num3   ...
field1  field2  field3  field4 ...
```

---

**Variant № 2**

```
awk '
function abs(n) {
    return (n < 0) ? -n : n
}
!/\)/{
    print abs($1 - $2)
}
' <(paste -d' ' <(sed '1,/(/d' file_1.txt) <(sed '1,/(/d' file_2.txt))
```

Comment: You should mention that `RS='[)(]'` requires an awk version that supports multi-char RS, e.g. GNU awk, it won't work with a standard POSIX awk. Regarding `/\)/` - you don't need to escape `)` in a regexp, it's only a metachar if preceded by a `(`.

Comment: @EdMorton `RS='[)(]'` works in **mawk** too.

Comment: @EdMorton `/)/` doesn't work in **mawk** - `echo -e ')one\n)two\nthree\n' | mawk '/)/{print}` yields `mawk: line 1: regular expression compile failed (missing '(')`, but works in **gawk**.

Comment: Regarding `/)/` then the version of mawk you're using is not POSIX compliant (I'm guessing you're using mawk1), you should get a new version that's at least POSIX compliant.

Comment: Regarding `RS='[)(]'` working in mawk, that doesn't change anything about my comment - you should give readers a warning that it requires non-POSIX functionality and won't work in all awks.

Answer (score -2):

```
sed -n -e '/(/,/)/p' file1|sed -e '1d' -e '$d' >file1_1
sed -n -e '/(/,/)/p' file2|sed -e '1d' -e '$d' >file2_1
paste file1_1 file2_1| awk '{print $2-$1}' >file3
```

output

```
cat file3
0.1
0.1
0.1
0.1
0.1
```